# An exercise about immersion and curves

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $\alpha : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ a immersion in class $C^1$, injective and had his inverse $\alpha^{-1} : \alpha(\mathbb{R}^2) \to \mathbb{R}^2$ continuous.

Let $\gamma : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is in class $C^1$ such that $\gamma(\mathbb{R}) \subset \alpha(\mathbb{R}^2)$ .

The question is to show the existence of a curve $\beta : (-\delta, \delta) \to \mathbb{R}^2$ in class $C^1$ such that
$$
\gamma(t) = \alpha(\beta(t)) \quad \forall t \in  (-\delta, \delta).
$$

Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If $\alpha$ is injective and has inverse, simply let $\beta(t) = \alpha^{-1}(\gamma(t))$. The domain of $\alpha^{-1}$ is $\alpha(\mathbb{R}^2$), and we know $\gamma(t)$ is in this set for any $t$, so the composition is valid. And since $\alpha$ is an immersion, its Jacobian is never zero, and it's inverse function has a nowhere zero Jacobian given by $J[\alpha^{-1}](p) = J[\alpha](\alpha^{-1}(p))^{-1}$, and so it is of class $C^1$. Composing it with the $C^1$ function $\gamma$ yields another $C^1$ function, so this $\beta$ is indeed differentiable. And since your inverse is defined globally, there is no need to restrict your equality to a neighborhood $(-\delta,\delta)$. If you were only given $\alpha$ has nonzero derivative at a point in $\alpha^{-1}(\gamma(0))$, then it would be necessary to introduce a bounded neighborhood.

Comment: Let $\alpha(x,y)=(\alpha_1(x,y),\alpha_2(x,y),\alpha_3(x,y)$. I know $$ J\frac{(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)}{(x,y)} \neq 0 $$. I dont know the inverse function is differentiable.

Comment: The statement that a differentiable function with locally nonzero derivative is locally invertible with nonzero derivative given by $J[f^{-1}](p) = J[f](f^{-1}(p))^{-1}$ is an important result in multivariable calculus called the Inverse Function Theorem. Do you not have access to this theorem?

Comment: I copied the wikipedia:

Comment: "The theorem states that if the total derivative of a continuously differentiable function $F$ defined from an open set $F$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$ is invertible at a point $p$ (i.e., the Jacobian determinant of $F$ at $p$ is non-zero), then $F$ is an invertible function near $p$. That is, an inverse function to $F$ exists in some neighborhood of $F(p)$. Moreover, the inverse function $F^{-1}$ is also continuously differentiable."


But, $\alpha : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$. Its ok, I think I need to use the local immersion theorem.